# C# drawtsring print only print certain part of the content in my deployed winform app

Tags: c#, printing, drawstring

Sample Printed Receipt in deployed app

[image: Sample Printed Receipt in deployed app]

Iam using graphic drawstring to print transaction receipt in my deployed cashier app(client device), when i test it by switching the printer to "print to pdf" nothing seems wrong, when i Run it in VS(in my device) then i test the printing using the same printer (Epson Lx 310) it printed the whole content, so the problem only affect in  my deployed app

I have done nothing because i am so confused of how its doing that